# Executorservice InvokeAll Timeout vs Future get Timeout

Tags: java, executorservice, threadpoolexecutor

We could pass waiting time limit as a parameter in invoke all method (or) future object get method

What difference it makes when timed out?

```
executorService.invokeAll(Arrays.asList(callabletask), 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

> vs

```
executorService.submit(callabletask).get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Answer (score 0):

`executorService.invokeAll(Arrays.asList(callabletask), 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);`
waits all tasks in the list to finish before timeout. If tasks don't finish before timeout expires method throws TimeoutException.

`executorService.submit(callabletask).get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);`
waits only one task (`callabletask`) to finish before timeout. This method also throws TimeoutException if task doesn't finish before timeout expires.

In this case both case are identical because you send list of one task which is `Arrays.asList(callabletask)`

You can see: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAll(java.util.Collection,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)